# springdata MongoDB batch inserts with continueOnError option

Tags: mongodb, spring-data-mongodb, batch-insert

MongoDB supports a continueOnError option so that batch insert continues even if there is a failure in a single document insertion.

Is there a way to achieve this using spring-data version 1.3.3.RELEASE. I am using the MongoOperations class and I don't see an API that allows me to do this.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should set this through the [writeConcern](http://api.mongodb.org/java/current/com/mongodb/WriteConcern.html#continueOnErrorForInsert%28boolean%29) options for [MongoTemplate](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-mongodb/docs/1.1.0.M1/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/MongoTemplate.html#setWriteConcern%28com.mongodb.WriteConcern%29)

```
mongoTemplate.setWriteConcern( 
    new WriteConcern(<Your options>).continueOnErrorForInsert(true));
```

Alternately there should be a constructor for for WriteConcern that does this as well.

More specifically as a usage, I set a Bean in a config class:

```
public @Bean
MongoTemplate mongoTemplate() throws Exception {
    MongoTemplate mongoTemplate = new MongoTemplate(mongoDbFactory());

    WriteConcern writeConcern = new WriteConcern(2);
    writeConcern.continueOnErrorForInsert(true);

    mongoTemplate.setWriteConcern(writeConcern);

    return mongoTemplate;
}
```

And then later on, set up the operations:

```
    MongoOperations mongoOperation = (MongoOperations) ctx.getBean("mongoTemplate");

    Collection collection = new Collection() { ... }

    mongoOperation.insert(collection,"collection");   // Uses the writeConcern options
```